# python call the meshlab snapshot function

Tags: python, meshlab, pymeshlab

I am new to meshlab, I can not find the function in **meshlabsever** or **pymeshlab**, and I want to take the snapshot in obj files.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OclGj.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That function is unique to meshlab, and does not exists in pymeshlab nor meshlabserver. It is not possible to implement it because they avoid to create a render context. This means that they lack of concepts like  camera position, background colour or number of lights, which is the basis of rendering.
If you really need to batch render a set of obj files, you can try using blender3D or pov-ray.

Comment: You are right, but I can load the texture by blender
import bpy

ob = bpy.context.active_object

tex = bpy.data.textures.new(name="Tex_Altura", type="IMAGE")
img = bpy.data.images.load("/home/orlando/Documentos/ProyectosBlender/TextureforSTL/heighmap.png")
tex.image = img
tex.extension = 'EXTEND'

mod = ob.modifiers.new("", 'DISPLACE')
mod.strength = 0.1
mod.mid_level = 0
mod.texture = tex

Answer (score 1):

If that can help 2 years later, I was able to take snapshots of a series of mesh files using [Polyscope](https://polyscope.run/) in Pymeshlab:

```
import polyscope as ps
ps.init()
ps.set_autocenter_structures(True)
ps.set_autoscale_structures(True)
ps.set_screenshot_extension(".jpg")
for mesh_file in all_meshes_files:
    print(mesh_file)
    ms.load_new_mesh(os.path.join(meshes_folder,mesh_file))
    m = ms.current_mesh()
    vertices = m.vertex_matrix()
    faces = m.face_matrix()
    ps_mesh = ps.register_surface_mesh("my mesh", vertices, faces)
    ps.reset_camera_to_home_view()
    ps.screenshot(os.path.join(meshes_folder, os.path.splitext(mesh_file)[0] + '_screenshot.jpg'))
    ps.remove_all_structures()
    ms.clear()
```

The idea is to set a Polyscope environment, load the meshes sequentially in Pymeshlab, get the faces/vertices of the mesh, and transfer them to Polyscope, which luckily has a function for snapshots. It's convoluted, but functionnal for quick overviews. I didn't play with the camera, textures etc.